# Noun translations from Classic of Mountains and Seas?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for an authoritative English list of people, places and things from [Classic of Mountains and Seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Mountains_and_Seas).

Anne Birrell has apparently done a translation [*The Classic of Mountains and Seas*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140447199). I haven't been able to find a readily available digital copy yet though. One review of the book also mention poor translations of nouns:

> The translations of the names of places are wrong and unacceptable.

Strassberg also has a book entitled [Chinese Bestiary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0520298519) which looks promising. There doesn't seem to be a digital book available though either.

Is there anywhere were I can find a good English list of beasts, names and places?

Comment: I don't know whether or not it fit your need. You can find translation of proper noun used in Taiwan on the following website. [國家教育研究院 雙語詞彙、學術名詞暨辭書資訊網](http://terms.naer.edu.tw)

Answer (score -1):

I am sure but it looks like there is no authentic translations for the items you are looking for. And I don't think you can find a list in English since no one has done that before. But if you want to study this, I am happy to help. Thank you.

Asule